# How to make my sidebar automatically open on page load on big sceen and close on small screen?

Tags: html, css

I want this sidebar to open automatically when I load or reload it on big screen(eg: PC screen) until I close it. And always be close on smartphone screen when I load or reload the page until I open it. Yaeh one more thing:
How can I make this sidebar open down the header and How can I set both openNav() and closeNav() in the button(class:openbtn)?

```html
<body>


<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
<header>
<picture>
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
  <a href="#" ><img src="auto.png" height="25px" width="25px"></a>
  <a href="#" ><img src="auto.png" height="25px" width="25px"></a>
  <a href="#" ><img src="auto.png" height="25px" width="25px"></a>
  </header>
</picture>

<section> 

  <h2>hi,,,</h2>
  <p>main</p>
  </section>
</div>

<!--
#e0f6ff;
-->

</body>
```

```css
body    {
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    margin:0px auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.sidebar {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111; /* Black*/
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidebar */
}

/* The sidebar links */
.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* The button used to open the sidebar */
.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}


/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s; /* If you want a transition effect */
  padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}

section{
    max-width:960px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px white solid;
}
header{
    border:1px black solid;
    max-width:960px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```
<script>
/* Set the width of the sidebar to 250px and the left margin of the page content to 250px */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

/* Set the width of the sidebar to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
}

</script>
```

Comment: You could just make the CSS never hide the navigation bar if the screen exceeds your limit. This way the users with a large screen will always see the navigation bar.

Comment: @Tim can you please tell me how? or share me a link to follow?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a few things in your code since there were a few flaws (some HTML tags were shuffled around).

You can see the changes here:
https://codepen.io/timyboy12345/pen/RwbJMmX

Instead of using javascript to change CSS, it now toggles a class that changes with:

```
document.getElementById('[ID]').classList.toggle("active")
```

I've also changed some CSS to position the sidebar. Please note style-wise this may not be the best sidebar. But I don't know where you will put this/how you will use it.

Comment: Just change the CSS of the .sidebar. But make sure the sidebar doesn't overlap the context when it is expanded. This will seem weird and doesn't provide a good user experience.